# Simulating OpenGLES on my MAC

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Im trying to build a small world editor for my iPhone game. Im trying to build an interface with regular controls (buttons, sliders etc.) and have an OpenGLES view for preview.

What is the best way to do this?

I tried recompiling Mesa (for OpenGLES) from scratch on my Mac but it fails.

Is there any other alternative to be able to create an OpenGLES view inside a standard Mac application?

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, thats probably too obvious, but the iOS Simulator simulates an OpenGL ES environment too.

Answer (score 0):

Not for nothing, but do you know about this?

[NSOpenGLView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenGLView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

It's not ES, but depending on exactly what you need, that may not matter.